# Best Way to Implement WGET and GREP in Python

Tags: python, wget

I'm trying to find the best or most efficient way to go about this.

I'm grabbing stock prices like this from a command line:

```
myhostname % wget -q http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amzn -O - | egrep "qwidget-dollar"                   
                                    <div id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">$1969.5992</div>
                        <div class="qwidget-dollar"><div>*&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></div>
```

I'm trying to put that into a python file and grab just the dollar amount.

```
url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amzn"
filename = wget.download(url)
print (filename)
```

That gives me the entire page. I'm not sure what the best way is to about grabbing that dollar value though. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `re` library, Python standard library implementation of regular expressions. The `requests` library is also a good tool to have under your belt for these kinds of tasks.

For example

```
import re 
import requests

url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amzn"
regex = '<div id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">$(.*?)</div>'

# Retrieve the page.
page_text = requests.get(url).text 
# Print the first capture group of the regular expression search.
print(re.match(regex, page_text).group(1))
```

However, for any more sophisticated HTML parsing tasks I'd recommend the `lxml.html` or `BeautifulSoup` libraries.

Comment: The ```group(1)``` was giving me an error so I removed it, but now I get "none" for the result. Maybe the regex needs to be changed?